# Grails - Is it possible to bind the fields within a JS object that has been posted (AJAX)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, grails, data-binding

Is it possible to customise data binding such that I can simply pass an object to an AJAX post request rather than having to list out all of the params (as per comment)?
The commented out line binds as expected.

```
submitNewUser: function () {
     const user = this.form
     this.$http.post(`https://localhost:8443/api/saveUser`,
     {data: user})
     // {userName: user.userName, firstName: user.firstName, lastName: user.lastName, title: user.title, email: user.email})
     .then(response => {
        let user = response.data
        this.users.push(user)
        this.user = {userName: '', firstName: '', lastName: '', title: '', email: ''}
     })
     .catch(ex => console.error('Unable to save user', ex))
}
```

Grails command object:

```
class SaveUserCommand {
    String userName
    String firstName
    String lastName
    String title
    String email
}
```

The form object:

```
  form: {
     userName: null,
     firstName: null,
     lastName: null,
     title: null,
     email: null,
  }
```

The JSON data structure being sent (as retrieved from devtools);

```
{
   data: {
      userName:  "New_user5"
      email:     "myemail@myuser.com"
      firstName: "New"
      lastName:  "User"
      title:     "User Admin"
   }
}
```

the JSON data structure that results from the commented out line of code;

```
{
   userName:  "New_user5"
   email:     "myemail@myuser.com"
   firstName: "New"
   lastName:  "User"
   title:     "User Admin"
}
```

I hope this clarifies the question somewhat.

Comment: Yes, - I would think user and your custom user would be equivalent objects - is there an issue?

Comment: Sure, but it does not bind. I guess because the commented out version comes in "flattened" while the user object comes in as `{user:{userName:''... }`.
Might be clearer if I just give it a consistent name like `data:`

Comment: I'm going to take a look at using an Interceptor. I just figured this would be a common one for the SPA with Grails (or whatever else) backend people. I'm new enough to this approach.

Comment: Of course I don't think the Interceptor idea is going to fly either because the request object's contents are read only

Comment: If your user object is that... why not just set `cost user = this.form.user`?

Comment: You my friend are talking about the magic of commandObjects https://guides.grails.org/command-objects-and-forms/guide/index.html

Comment: Thanks @Orubel. You will see from the question that I'm indeed already using command objects. It's the binding thereof that I am querying.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your command object is validateable, i.e. is it either in the same file as the controller, or if not, is it annotated with `@Validateable`?

If you're sure it's validateable, can you execute `JSON.stringify(user)` in the browser console (dev tools), so we can see the structure of the data you're sending?

### Update

It seems this is the structure of the data you're sending:

```
{
  user: {
    userName:  "New_user5"
    email:     "myemail@myuser.com"
    firstName: "New"
    lastName:  "User"
    title:     "User Admin"
  }
}
```

And you're trying to bind it to:

```
class SaveUserCommand {
    String userName
    String firstName
    String lastName
    String title
    String email
}
```

Binding is failing because the objects don't have the same properties, so you have two choices:

### Option 1: Change the request data

Send this instead:

```
{
  userName:  "New_user5"
  email:     "myemail@myuser.com"
  firstName: "New"
  lastName:  "User"
  title:     "User Admin"
}
```

I would expect this to be the easier of the 2 options, you probably just need to replace:

```
{data: user}
```

with:

```
{data: this.form.user}
```

### Option 2: Change the command object

Bind the request data to this instead

```
@Validateable
class SaveUserCommand {
    UserData user
}

@Validateable
class UserData {
    String userName
    String firstName
    String lastName
    String title
    String email
}
```

Comment: Command object is indeed in same file as controller. I should say that I feel I understand why it is not binding, because the props have become members of the parent "data" object. But I'm wondering if there is any way around this.

Comment: @dre I don't know what you mean by "parent data object". In your code above `user`, `data`, and `this.form` are all referring to the same object

Comment: I'll edit the question but to try and explain, when I submit the form using the method of verbosely listing out all of object properties (commented out line in question), the JSON structure is flat and so all of the properties are at the top level. When I try and send the `user` object, this results in a parent `data` object at the top level of the JSON structure and so it does not bind. 
I'm wondering if there is a way of processing this instead of having to list the properties every time.

Comment: Thanks @Dónal. Option 1 is most certainly what I'm _trying_ to achieve and to just clarify your suggestion, my `form` object in the question would now have to have a sub property called `user` under which all of the properties would exist.
`form: { user : { userName: "", firstName: "", ... }`

Comment: I have tried **Option 1**, and it does not bind to the command object. I guess therein lies my problem. **Option 2** is not really what I'm looking for, but thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should add the action to your post as well, just in case you're not using the command object correctly

Comment: well it would be better to 'implements Validateable' (we dont know where this class is going to be used) and the you can always put in constraints as well (like in your domains)